# How to execute filters in List<Function> in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of functions i want to execute after loop throw them

```
late List<Function> filters = [];`





 for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
       filters[i]();
    }
```

How I add the functions:

```
filters.add(()=> User.filterAdmin(copyWorkers!));
```

It's not working the execution on loop.
How I fix this?

Comment: How do you mean it's not working? Is an error thrown somewhere?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.